# Linux: USB 2.0 ports no longer functional

Tags: linux, usb

I found my once functional USB 2.0 ports disabled or just dead:

```
$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:b009 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0438:7900 Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 05c8:0233 Cheng Uei Precision Industry Co., Ltd (Foxlink) HP Webcam
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Kernel `5.2.21-1-MANJARO`

The 2.0 ports can see neither USB sticks nor my phone. The USB stick LED is shining, but that's all.

`lsusb` output does not change after inserting a stick into a 2.0 port.

```
$ sudo dmesg | grep USB
[11563.020957] usb 1-1.4: reset full-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-pci
```

I'm not sure I'm using `dmesg` in a meaningful way, though.

Is there a way to make sure whether it is a hardware of software (kernel?) trouble?

Comment: "I'm not sure I'm using dmesg in a meaningful way, though" – Case-insensitive search may be better: `sudo dmesg | grep -i USB`.

Comment: Nothing interesting there, I'm afraid. `Modules linked in: ... usb_storage ... btusb ... usb 1-1.4: reset full-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-pci`

Comment: What do you mean by "found"? Suddenly, without any changes from your side? After a software upgrade? If the latter, try installing earlier kernel(s), and see if it starts working again. If the former, try different USB ports/USB hubs (if you can) to reduce the chance of a hardware malfunction.

Comment: It used to work with the current kernel. So it may or may not be a hardware malfunction. I'd like to discover the nature of my problem.

Comment: actually `tail` makes more sense than any `grep` in such (if not all) case...or even just `dmesg -l 3` or `4`...there's also `-w` btw

Comment: I have my USB 2.0 ports back. Just as gratuitously as lost them. No reboot, even. I like it not at all, but that's that.